# Call javascript Actions on a local website in a WKWebView

Tags: javascript, html, ios

I am using Xcode 9.0 and iOS 11. I'm trying to execute javascript code, when the user taps a link. The js-code is embedded in a local html website, within a WKWebView.
I tried many suggestions like using `webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementsByClassName('panel-title').innerText")`or set different configurations for the webview.
The html site contains a PrivacyPolicy where the user can expand and collapse different sections

It looks like this:

```
<main class="container">
      <div>
      <h1 id="datenschutzwbrerklrung">Datenschutz<wbr>erklärung</h1>
          <p>Allgemein</p></div>
          <div class="panel panel-default"><div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingsection1" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#section1">
              <h4 class="panel-title">Allgemeiner Hinweis</h4></div><div id="section1" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingsection1"><div class="panel-body">
              <p>Es ist uns ein ganz besonderes Anliegen, dass sich alle Nutzer unserer App wohl und sicher fühlen. Aus diesem Grund ist uns der Schutz Ihrer personenbezogenen Daten von höchster Wichtigkeit.
                  Bei der Erhebung, Verarbeitung und Nutzung halten wir uns selbstverständlich streng an die gesetzlichen Bestimmungen des Bundesdatenschutzgesetzes (BDSG) und des Telemediengesetzes (TMG).
                  Wir verarbeiten personenbezogene Daten zur Auftragsabwicklung. Bei berechtigtem Interesse rufen wir zum Zweck der eigenen Kreditprüfung ggf. Bonitätsinformationen von Auskunfteien ab.</p></div></div></div>

          <br />
```

So when user clicks on "Allgemeiner Hinweis". The text below expands. This is working in Safari on a Mac (JavaScript must be activated). But it doesn't work in my WKWebView. 
My Current WKWebView configuration looks like this:

```
var webView: WKWebView!

    override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()

        let contentController = WKUserContentController()
        let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()

        config.preferences.javaScriptEnabled = true
        config.preferences.javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true
        config.selectionGranularity = .character
        config.userContentController = contentController

        webView = WKWebView()
        webView.navigationDelegate = self

        self.webView.customUserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36 Edge/12.10136"
        view = webView

    }
```

I also use the following delegate method. The first if condition is always false. For the second if statement error and result is nil.

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        print("delegate")

        webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementsByClassName('panel-title').innerText") { (result, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print(result ?? "nix")
            }
            else {
                print("Error: \(String(describing: error))")
            }
        }
        webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementsByClassName('panel-title')") { (result, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print("The result is: \(result ?? "nil")")
            print("resut error: \(error!)")
            }
        else {
            print("The Error: \(String(describing: error))")
            }

        }
```

I'm sure there is still missing something.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I can't post the whole javascript part because its over 3000 lines of code. It seems there is also some query involved. Maybe someone can give me some kind of general hint how to make this work

Answer (score 0):

Try setting custom user agent property to WKWebView.

Objective C

```
[self.webView setCustomUserAgent:@"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36 Edge/12.10136"];
```

Swift

```
self.webView.customUserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36 Edge/12.10136"
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this did not solve my problem. Now I added the following line to my code. `config.preferences.javaScriptEnabled = true` but also this has no effect. I dont't know why

Comment: Can you please edit the question to show how you are defining WKWebView.

Comment: I edited the deklaration and definition of the WKWebView (middle code part)

Comment: Now I got an error value. its in German but you can look at the error name und the error-code: `Error Domain=WKErrorDomain Code=5 "JavaScript-Ausführung hat ein Ergebnis in Form eines nicht unterstützten Typs ausgegeben" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=JavaScript-Ausführung hat ein Ergebnis in Form eines nicht unterstützten Typs ausgegeben}` It says: The result has an unsupported Type

Comment: I uploaded the html file to google-drive: here ist the link: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2WLxhNr7Zr4MEZKTG9KakRrT1E

Comment: try moving your code from loadView() to viewDidLoad() and check and let me know.